# Collapsing Side Menu for a website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

What I wanna do is create a hovering side menu for a website, But since I'm new to web designing I'm bit Lost, as seen in [this example](http://www.cryptrade.com/#/home) what I want to achieve is something like side "Contact Us" form and Social media sharing menus. But I want to create this by using html5 css or Java scripts. I have tried many things with Bootstrap jQuery but no luck so far so I would really appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to want to set the css style of the contact block element you want off the page to `position: absolute; right: n` (where `n` = the width of the button you want sticking out the side). When the link is clicked, your jQuery function should increase `n` to the width of the full div you initially had hidden.

Basically, you're just rendering the contact box off the right edge of the page and moving it out. Contactable should take care of that for you though, so if that fits your needs then it might be easier.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're searching for [Contactable](http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Slide-Out-Contact-Form-Plugin-with-jQuery-Contactable.html)

With the correct adaptation, you can achieve the same result from the example you gave.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks I'll play with the codes and see.